# What is the most Professional way of referencing an object's "this" in an addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object constructor function that I use to create an object for a Conway's Game of Life simulator. A table element is used to render the game and the cells.

A user can click on a cell to toggle it being alive/dead.
For this reason, every cell has an event listener,

```
cell.addEventListener( 'click', myObjConstructor.toggleState )
```

The way handlers work is that when the listener calls the handler function, "*this*" refers to the element the listener is placed in (rather than the object's *this*) which is why this wouldn't work:

```
cell.addEventListener( 'click', this.toggleState )
```

Because this would reference the element (the cell) which wouldn't have a "toggleState" method thus results in an error.

I think this is pretty standard knowledge regarding handlers. My question is, what is the most "professional" way of dealing with this when you want to reference the object's *this*?

The way I am dealing with it is I declare this dummy variable at the beginning of my object:

```
myBackupThis = this;
```

However, this feels "cheap". I am assuming the pros must handle it in a different way.

I tried an arrow function but it doesn't solve the problem that "this" is not pointing to the object.

Comment: `this.toggleState.bind(this)`

Comment: An arrow function should work just fine. What exactly did you try?

Comment: What is the context of that line of code in your question ? Where is the `cell.addEventListener` being called from ?

Comment: `I tried an arrow function`,  If you tried -> `cell.addEventListener( 'click', () => this.toggleState() )`  then `this` would be the same `this` that you invoked it with.  Please note if you use an arrow function, don't forget you also need to invoke the function,  IOW:  `() => func()`, and not `() => func`..

Comment: _“every cell has an event listener”_ — Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of adding several event listeners — it’s more maintainable and applies to dynamically added elements. See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [this Q&A](/q/1687296/4642212).